# Boundary of solution of $y'=A(x)y$ for continuous bounded $A$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Given an $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and a continuous, bounded function $A:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, I want to show that every solution $\phi:[a,\infty)\mapsto\mathbb{R}^n$ of the ODE $$y'=A(x)y$$ has $\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log\lvert\lvert\phi(x)\rvert\rvert}{x}<\infty$ as growth-boundary, where $\lvert\lvert\cdot\rvert\rvert$ is any norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So far I tried to find a contradiction by assuming that $\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log\lvert\lvert\phi(x)\rvert\rvert}{x}=\infty$ for some solution $\phi$, which would mean that $\log\lvert\lvert\phi(x)\rvert\rvert$ grows faster than $x$, i.e. (I assumed $\phi(x)>0$ because this seemed easier for the beginning) $\frac{\phi'(x)}{\phi(x)}>1$ for all $x$, which in turn would mean that since $\phi$ is a solution of the ODE $\lvert\lvert A(x)\rvert\rvert\lvert\lvert \phi(x)\rvert\rvert >\lvert\lvert\phi(x)\rvert\rvert$, i.e. $\lvert\lvert A(x)\rvert\rvert>1$ for all $x$. But I'm afraid this is not the right approach at all.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying both sides of the equation by $\phi(x)$ we get
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\|\phi\|^2=2\,\phi'\cdot\phi=2\,(A\,\phi)\cdot\phi.
$$
Since $A$ is bounded there is a constant $M>0$ such that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\|\phi\|^2\le M\,\|\phi\|^2.
$$
Integrating we get
$$
\|\phi(x)\|^2\le \|\phi(a)\|^2\,e^{M(x-a)},\quad x\ge a.
$$

Comment: How do you get the $e^{M(x-a)}$ from integrating?

Comment: Let $z(x)=\|\phi(x)\|^2$. Then $z'/z=(\log z)'\le M$ and $\log z(x)\le\log(z(a))+M(x-a)$.